# Router navigation inside for loop in angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, for-loop, routes

I'm trying to open multiple tab views using **router.navigate** in angular. Please find the below code snippet

```
 async onVisualizeMultipleRecordsClick() {
    for (const row of this.multipleSelectedRowsData) {
      await this.router.navigate([`device/${row.data.uuid}`]);
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300)); // Add a delay of 0.3 second (adjust as needed)
    }
  }
```

But If I removed **await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));** from above snippet some routes will not open( Means if I have 5 routes in my loop, only 3 will get opened). Is there any solution without using the **setTimeout** to navigate to all these routes?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem or error you're having, ideally in an online code editor like [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Comment: what is the purpose of using `navigate` inside a loop ?

Comment: @brk  to open new route inside a tab